# How to explain different, seemingly inconsistent, values for the mass of the alpha particle in different books?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, radioactivity, binding-energy, textbook-erratum

I’m trying to calculate the energy of an $\alpha$ particle after the decay of Ra-226 following an example in a german school book and came across different values for the mass of an $\alpha$ particle.

- Dorn·Bader (school book), Giancoli Physik (text book): $m_1 = 4.002603\,\mathrm{u}$
- Cornelsen Tafelwerk (formulary): $m_2 = 4.001228\,\mathrm{u}$
- [GNU `units`](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/units.html), [NIST](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?malu), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_particle), [Phys. Rev. Lett. 92, 220802 (2004)](http://www.roentgen.physik.uni-goettingen.de/%7Emosterh/PhysRevLett.92.220802.pdf): $m_3 = 4.001506\,\mathrm{u}$

$m_1$ seems to be the mass of a neutral Helium atom, according to an appendix in Giancoli and the Phys. Rev. article. Dorn·Bader also stated that the particle gets two electrons of Rn-222 after the decay. Thus it makes sense to use $m_1 = m_\mathrm{He}$ for the calculation (which leads to an energy matching an energy spectrum). But why are there different values $m_2$ and $m_3$? Is my formulary just outdated?

---

**printed sources**

Dorn·Bader Physik, Sekundarstufe II Nds. 12/13, 2019, p. 235

[image: dorn-bader book page]

Giancoli Physik, 2016, p. 1409

[image: giancoli book page]

Cornelsen, Das große Tafelwerk Interaktiv 2.0, 2018, p. 117

[image: tafelwerk book page]

Comment: How about a screen shot of each book page that shows this?

Comment: I added the images but I’m pretty sure I copied the values correctly ;-) and the formulary and Giancoli give no context for why they print/use their value. Dorn·Bader states that the alpha particle collects two electrons, but doesn't mention explicitly that this is the reason for using m_He

Comment: I think it's a typo/mistake. m_1 is the mass of the entire helium-4 atom, and m_3 is the mass of the helium-4 nucleus. I honestly can't figure out how they could have obtained m_2 from the provided values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speculate on the value of the Cornelsen book, but for both Dorn Bader and Giancoli the mass value is the standard atomic weight value for Helium bar the last digit, i.e., the weighted average of a He sample that contains both $^3$He and $^4$He, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium) for a primary source. Since $^3$He is so sparse, the weighted average is really close to the $^4$He weight anyway. Dorn Bader is incorrect for giving this value as the alpha particle mass.

I've done some calculations with different combinations of proton and neutron masses, with reduced accuracy etc., but none of them come close to the value of Cornelsen, since it's lower than the NIST value. My best guess is a calculation with low accuracy historical values, probably copied over from an older formulary the publishing company themselves published.

Comment: Thanks. That's seems to make sense and I just accept that Cornell's printed a wrong value. Btw. Dorn·Bader states that the particle collects two electrons however it doesn’t make clear that this is the reason for using the higher mass.